# SQL - Unique results

Tags: sql

Could you, please, help me to build a SELECT using SQL?

I have the following table:

```
Table: Delivery | Columns: (idProvider, idMaterial, idProject, quantity)
```

I would like to select all projects `(idProject)` where the only provider `(idProvider)` was provider = 1.

P.S: A project can have many providers.

I've tried the trivial:

```
 Select (SELECT idProject FROm Delivery WHERE idProvider = 1)
```

but it does not work, because it returns projects that have more than one provider.

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL Server or MySQL?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: It's a homework? Exists the table provider?

Comment: is this sql server or mysql?

Comment: Its a homework, try it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT foo.idProject
FROM Delivery AS foo
LEFT JOIN Delivery AS bar
  ON foo.idProject = bar.idProject
    AND bar.idProvider <> 1
WHERE foo.idProvider = 1
  AND bar.idProject IS NULL;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but, thank you very much! It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to AgRizzo's answer (because that approach has always made my head hurt) this should work:

```
Select
idProject
from
delivery

group by
idProject
having

count (case when idProvider = 1 then 1 else null end) = 1
and count (idProvider) = 1
```